# Math mode Error

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to compile this:

```latex
\center
\clearpage
\begin{table}
\caption{. U.S. Stock Return Predictability}
\caption*{\small Table II shows return predictability for the U.S. equity market, December 1986 to May 2014, 330 monthly observations. The regression is:\\

\begin{equation*}
\frac{{12}}{h}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^h {\log {R_{t + i}} - } \log R_{t + i}^f = {\beta _0} + {\beta _1}GLDRI{X_{innov}} + {\varepsilon _{t + h}}
\end{equation*}



The left had side variable is the excess return on the CRSP value-weighted index, annualized by horizon h. The right hand side predictor is $GLDRIX_{innov}$. The returns are calculated based on overlapping monthly data, and t-statistics are based on Newey and West (1987) HAC robust standard errors.}
\include{det1}
\label{table:II}
\end{table}
```

and I get the following error:

```
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

Would you please help me with this?

Comment: Why did you place an equation and some text inside the caption of a table environment? What kind of layout do you want to achieve?

Comment: works fine for me, if I just copy paste an compile it

Comment: @Nima: Please add the documentclass as well as the relevant packages in order to create a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: `equation*` is not defined by default, did you get an error about that?

Comment: unrelated but the command form is `\centering` not `\center`

Comment: you should never use `\include` inside a table environment, either use `\input` or move the `\include` outside the table.

Comment: The problem is about what is inside the equation. When I erase the equation and what it contains the whole problem goes away.

Comment: @Nima you have not provided an example that anyone can run to see the error, so we can only comment on what is there.

Comment: What's in `det1.tex`?

Comment: It does not appear that the `\caption*{` command is ever closed with a `}`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the `\caption*` wrapper at all.

[image]

You'll notice that I've removed *a lot* of curly braces from the equation as they don't do anything except code clutter. I can't help but observe that the regression equation still doesn't look right; e.g., shouldn't `\mathrm{GLDRIX}_{\mathrm{innov}}` have a time-`t` subscript?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable doc. class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' env.
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{U.S. stock return predictability}
\label{table:II}

\begingroup
\small % <-- is this really needed?
This table shows return predictability for the U.S. equity market, 
December 1986 to May 2014, 330 monthly observations. 
The regression equation is:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{12}{h}\sum_{i=1}^h \log R_{t+i} - \log R_{t+i}^f 
= \beta_0 + \beta_1\mathrm{GLDRIX}_{\mathrm{innov}} + \varepsilon_{t + h}
\end{equation*}
The left hand side variable is the excess return on the CRSP 
value-weighted index, annualized by horizon $h$. The right hand 
side predictor is $\mathrm{GLDRIX}_{\mathrm{innov}}$. The returns 
are calculated based on overlapping monthly data, and $t$-statistics 
are based on Newey and West (1987) HAC robust standard errors.
\endgroup

%\centering
%\input det1 % does 'det1.tex' contain some tabular material?

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks.